# How do I get Selenium server working with htmlunit?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

I downloaded selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar and ran it like this to get a list of supported browsers:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0.jar -interactive
cmd=getNewBrowserSession
```

Unfortunately, htmlunit isn't in that list, but when I look at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver), it says it supports it quite clearly, yet I've had little success so far.

Does anyone know how to get htmlunit working with Selenium Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use htmlunit webdriver or webdriver backed selenium. You can utilise [QAF (formerly ISFW)](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) as well.

Comment: sorry this is where i'm slightly confused - is webdriver the same as selenium?

Comment: webdriver known as selenium 2. If you are newer to selenium, selenium IDE is the best way to learn selenium. Record using ide,  export test in webdriver format and run it.